# Moving Passport Google strategy authenticate method from route to controller breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am using the 'passport-google-oauth' strategy from Passport with Nodejs based Express app to provide authentication. This worked great when I had the logic inside the route file as follows:

```
router.route('/auth/google')
    .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']
    });
);
```

When I moved everything into a controller to make the app more manageable, it stopped working. Specifically, no error is being thrown. The GET request succeeds and the debug method outputs the string, but then it just loads forever and I'm not being redirected to the Google page to select which account to log in with. Any ideas what is going on here and what I need to change to make it flow like fine wine?

```
// route file
router.route('/auth/google')
    .get(backendController.googleAuthenticate);

// controller file
exports.googleAuthenticate = () => {
    debug('attempting Google authentication');
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'],
        failWithError: true
    });
}
```